# Issue with float.Parse in Unity Android App

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, parsing, floating-point

I develop an Android app. If I call

```
float.Parse("51.552058")
```

in Editor or App on my Mac Book (Language Setting English), it works fine. After publishing to Android (Language Setting German) the result of the Parse operation is not "51.552058" anymore but "5,155211E+09". I understand that this might be related to the device's language but I still don't really understand what is happening and why.

I also tried following with no success:

```
float.Parse("51.552058", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any)

float.Parse("51.552058", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint)
```

Did anyone stumble over this before?

Answer (score 0):

[`float.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.single.parse) is culture dependent.

See e.g. from [`NumberFormatInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo#parsing-numeric-strings)

> ```
> //       '1,034,562.91' --> 1034562.91 (en-US)
> //       '1,034,562.91': FormatException (fr-FR)
> //       '1,034,562.91' --> 1034562.91 (Invariant)
> ```

Reason here is that in EU cultures the `,` is usually the decimal separator while the `.` is used as the group separator. So from the example above the correct format for `fr-FR` would be `1.034.562,91`

You probably rather want to use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) like

```
float.Parse("51.552058", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or directly [`NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.invariantinfo#System_Globalization_NumberFormatInfo_InvariantInfo)

```
float.Parse("51.552058", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

which simply has defined

> ```
> NumberDecimalSeparator          .
> NumberGroupSeparator            ,
> ```